# Media-Element.js and Wordpress Usage

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

I understand that media-element.js is now part of the WordPress core according to mejs website. How do I use it with WordPress?

Is there documentation somewhere besides what is on mejs website?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```